# Cron job does not start

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

I have a cron job that I want to execute every 5 minutes:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /scr_temp/scheduleSpider.sh
```

In `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`

The cron should execute a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -f "sync.txt" ]; then
    touch "sync.txt"
    chmod 777 /scr_temp
    curl someLink
fi
```

That works fine from command line but not from cron. However the cron itself is startet but the script does not start.

I read about the path problem but I dont really understand it. I setup a cron that writes some env data to a file. This is the output:

```
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
SHELL=/bin/sh
```

If I execute the env command in command line I get following output for PATH

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

What path do I have to set in my shell script?

Comment: It looks like this would actually do things only once, unless you delete `sync.txt`.

Comment: In what cron file are you putting the line? It looks like it should work.

Comment: I put it in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$PATH` is fine; leave it alone.  On Ubuntu, all the commands you're invoking (`touch`, `chmod`, `curl`) are in `/bin` and/or `/usr/bin`.

How did you set up the cron job?  Did you run `crontab some-file` as root?

It seems that `/etc/crontab` is the usual mechanism for running cron commands as root.  On my Ubuntu system, `sudo crontab -l` says `no crontab for root`.  Running `crontab` as root, as you would for any non-root account, should be ok, but you might consider using `/etc/crontab` instead.  Note that it uses a different syntax than an ordinary crontab, as explained in the comments at the top of `/etc/crontab`:

```
$ head -5 /etc/crontab
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
```

Run `sudo crontab -l`.  Does it show your command?

Temporarily modify your script so it always produces some visible output.  For example, add the following right after the `#!/bin/sh`:

```
echo "Running scheduleSpider.sh at \`date\`" >> /tmp/scheduleSpider.sh.log
```

and see what's in `/tmp/scheduleSpider.sh.log` after a few minutes.  (You can set the command to run every minute so you don't have to wait as long for results.)  If that works (it should), you can add more `echo` commands to your script to see in detail what it's doing.

It looks like your script is designed to run only once; it creates the `sync.txt` file to prevent it from running again.  That could be the root (ahem) of your problem.  What that your intent?  Did you mean to delete `sync.txt` after running the command, and just forgot to do it?

`root`'s home directory on Ubuntu is `/root`.  The first time your script runs, it should create `/root/sync.txt`.  Does that file exist?  If so, how old is it?

Note that `curl someLink` (assuming `someLink` is a valid URL) will just dump the content from the specified link to standard output.  Was that your intent (it will show up as e-mail to `root`?  Or did you just not show us the entire command?

Comment: ok, when I put an echo at the top of my script I get an email with the output, so this seems to work but why does touch and curl not work?

Comment: Try the other things I suggested.  If you got the output of the `echo` by e-mail, then you ignored my advice to redirect the output to a file in `/tmp`.  Your cron job, as you showed it to us, is designed to run only once.  `touch` and `curl` should work fine; you're just not invoking them.

Comment: I check if sync.txt exists, for now it doesnt and the code in the if block should be executed, sync should be created but it doesnt, the curl command which should be executed starts a spider which after finishing deletes the sync file so that another spider can start, I do this to ensure that only one spider is active at a time, this works fine from command line. I tries your echo command but it seems to be not valid, there is a " missing somewhere?

Comment: I just realized that touch works, the file is created in root

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: Yes, there was a missing `"`; I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

First: you can substitute the first field with `*/5` (see man 5 crontab)
Second: have cron mail the output to your email address by entering `MAILTO=your@email.address` in your crontab. If the script has any output, it'll be mailed. Instead of that, you may have a local mailbox in which you can find the cron output (usually $MAIL).

Answer (score 1):

A better syntax for you CRON is

```
*/5 * * * * /scr_temp/scheduleSpider.sh
```

Also, check the authority of your `scheduleSpider.sh` file. Cron runs under a different user than the one you are likely executing your program interactively, so it may be that cron does not have authority. Try `chmod 777` for now, just to check.

Comment: @Codemwnci: No, cron jobs run under the same account as the user who executed the `crontab` command.  The cron daemon itself runs as root, but it switches to the appropriate user account when it invokes the commands.

Comment: indeed. I am used to a corporate environment, where the crontab is created by a user different to the one running the command on the command line. However, reading the question again, I suspect you are right, and the user is likely the same.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to:

- check that `/scr_temp/scheduleSpider.sh` has executable bit
- set `PATH` properly inside your script or use absolute path to command (`/bin/touch` instead of `touch`)
- specify absolute path to `sync.txt` file (or calculate it relatively to script)

Comment: what PATH do I have to set in my shell script?

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: You shouldn't have to set `$PATH` explicitly at all.  The default `$PATH` for cron jobs should definitely include the directory that contains the `touch` command (could be `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, or both).

Comment: Hm can you post this as an answer and describe it a bit?  I just did not get what I have to change...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the comand via `crontab -e` or just by editing the crontab file? You should use `crontab -e` to get it correctly updated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the working directory in the cron script, it probably doesn't execute the things where you think it should.

Answer (score 0):

You should add /bin/sh before the absolute path of your script.

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /scr_temp/scheduleSpider.sh
```